# How to compare two dataframes with multiple data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I am trying to compare two dataframes and print the difference. When I try to compare I get a "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Here are samples of the dataframes I am comparing.

```
      Name             NetAmount
0   AARON, ANN           440.40
1   AARON, BARBARA       334.23
2   AARON, XAVIER        378.09
3   ABBOTT, KEIFER       469.13
4   ABDO, WALEED         442.87
5   ABEDI, JONAS         466.69
6   ABELL, ASHLEY        288.09
7   ABOKO, HENRY         570.29
8   ABREU, IRVING        500.83
9   ABUHAMRA, ABDULAZIZ  429.73

     Name              NetAmount
0   AARON, ANN          371.70
1   AARON, BARBARA      357.89
2   AARON, XAVIER       406.46
3   ABBOTT, KEIFER      388.57
4   ABDO, WALEED        442.87
5   ABEDI, JONAS        466.69
6   ABOKO, HENRY        467.51
7   ABREU, IRVING       821.19
8   ABUHAMRA, ABDULAZIZ 422.77
9   ABUKHDAIR, ADAM     348.86

Name       Object
NetAmount  Float64
```

This is what I tried that gave me the error:

```
if a.Name != b.Name:
   print(a.Name)
else:
   pass
```

Comment: What about these dataframe columns/series are you trying to compare? If they contain all the same elements, if they're the same length, find all the elements in one that aren;t in the other...? It would help if you [edit] to include your expected output based on these inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be generic that the 2 dataframes can be of different sizes, you can compare values in dataframe `a` column `Name` with the list of all `Name` fields in dataframe `b`.    Repeat for the other side.

Build mask of a.Name not in b.Name.to_list() then use `.loc[]` to select. Similarly for the other way round:

```
mask1 = ~a.Name.isin(b.Name.to_list())
print(a.loc[mask1])

mask2 = ~b.Name.isin(a.Name.to_list())
print(b.loc[mask2])
```

Output:

```
            Name  NetAmount
6  ABELL, ASHLEY     288.09
              Name  NetAmount
9  ABUKHDAIR, ADAM     348.86
```

Or, if you just need to print the Name field:

```
print(a.Name.loc[mask1])
print(b.Name.loc[mask2])

6    ABELL, ASHLEY
Name: Name, dtype: object
9    ABUKHDAIR, ADAM
Name: Name, dtype: object
```